# MySQL query with specific constraints?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create MySQL queries to answer some questions after creating the following database:

```
create table teachers (
    teacher_id int primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(50),
    surname varchar(50),
    dob date,
    employment_day date
);

create table students (
    student_id int primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(50),
    surname varchar(50),
    dob date,
    no_of_lessons_left int
);

create table aircrafts (
    aircraft_id int primary key auto_increment,
    manufacturer varchar(50),
    serial_number varchar(50),  -- or int?
    cycles int
);

create table schools (
    school_id int primary key auto_increment,
    address varchar(50),
    opening_date date
);

create table lessons (
    lesson_id int primary key auto_increment,
    teacher_id int not null,
    student_id int not null,
    aircraft_id int not null,
    school_id int not null,
    lesson_date date,
    constraint lessons_teacher foreign key(teacher_id) references teachers(teacher_id),
    constraint lessons_student foreign key(student_id) references students(student_id),
    constraint lessons_aircraft foreign key(aircraft_id) references aircrafts(aircraft_id),
    constraint lessons_school foreign key(school_id) references schools(school_id)
);
```

Below some queries, I tried for the questions using double join:
Questions are : 
• How many aircraft are there per each school at some point in time?  
I can't figure out how to answer these conditions " **per each** school **at some point** of time" 

• How many students are attending one particular school?

```
select count(*) from students s 
inner join lessons l on  l.student_id = s.student_id 
inner join schools sc sc.teacher_id= l.teacher_id
where sc.name = "PilotingSchoolName";
```

• How many students does each teacher have at some particular moment

```
select count(*) from students s 
inner join lessons l on  l.student_id = s.student_id 
inner join schools sc sc sc.teacher_id= l.teacher_id;
```

However, I'm missing the condition " **at some particular moment** " in the query I wrote.

Comment: I'll flesh this out as an answer, as there's more to your other queries also.

Comment: When you see "per each x", it suggests GROUP BY x. Then aggregate calls apply per x/group. Learn about GROUP BY & aggregates.  (Aggreate calls without GROUP BY take the whole table as one group.) This is a faq.  Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Too many question for one question.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `lessons.lesson_date` column, and can limit to one point in time with something like AND `lesson_date = '2019-12-08'` or a date range with `AND lesson_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2019-12-08'`. If the requirements did not ask you to find a specific exact date, it sounds like they'd just like you to be able to demonstrate how to use lesson_date in `WHERE`.

In your response to "how many students does each teacher have" problem, you are missing a crucial `GROUP BY` clause. The query you have now is close, but will instead show the total number of enrolled students. Grouping by `teachers.name` will complete the query (along with a `lesson_date` constraint)

```
select
  t.name,
  -- count each student only once per teacher
  count(DISTINCT s.student_id) AS 
from teachers t
  -- left join so teachers with no enrolled
  -- students will list as zero
  left join lessons l on t.teacher_id = l.teacher_id 
  left join students s ON l.student_id = s.student_id
WHERE
  -- A specific date
  l.lesson_date = '2019-12-08'
GROUP BY t.name
```

To get the aircrafts per school at a particular time, the query is very similar, but with different joins.

```
select
  -- List all schools, and count of aircraft per school
  s.school_id,
  count(DISTINCT l.aircraft_id)
from
  schools s
  -- left join, so that schools with zero current aircraft
  -- are include in the results
  left join lessons l ON l.school_id = s.school_id
where
  l.lesson_date = '2019-12-08'
-- GROUP BY necessary to get the count per school
GROUP BY s.school_id
```

Comment: Just an addition, I think it is better to use left join to include entries with 0 values.

Comment: Agree, will add above.

Comment: For the remaining query "How many students are attending one particular school?" I edited my code to ```select count(*) from students s 
inner join lessons l on  l.student_id = s.student_id 
inner join schools sc sc.teacher_id= l.teacher_id
where sc.name = "PilotingSchoolName"; ```

Comment: @Slach Yes, that should complete it.